# Cannot delete post, "an error has occurred"

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-delete

I'm trying to delete [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181167/c-persistent-call-to-dll/5181901#5181901).  No luck, getting an orange "An error has occurred - please retry your request" box.  Retrying repeatedly doesn't accomplish anything.

Looking at the "Oops" http response with Firebug, I'm seeing this phrase:

```
<!-- Actual error:
Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.
-->
```

Comment: Hmm, I didn't have a problem with it. That post was flagged by Community to inform us that you might be vandalizing your own posts (I have no idea why it thinks so); perhaps the system is stopping you?

Comment: @mmyers - maybe because I tried to delete it a dozen times?  The oops response looks like a genuine .NET exception to me.

Comment: Maybe so. I've never seen that kind of auto-flag before, so I don't know what triggers it.

Comment: I will of course fix the script error as well...

Comment: @Hans - the lolcat was my last-minute "tested fine, but let's improve that message" tweak... let's just say `string.Format("blah {0} more blah")`... spot the error...

Comment: I see it, comma "lolz".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a recent change, that attempts to prevent wide-scale destruction of content, which sadly happens occasionally. There is a nominal cap on the number of **your own** posts that you can delete per day. Have you deleted many?

It is odd that the message came up wrong; that was meant to explain everything...

I'm **guessing** that at least some of the deletes were things that you posted very recently (today/yesterday), but better answers have been posted or the question altered; so I'll tweak it to not count posts from today/yesterday in that.

Comment: Not quite sure, maybe two or three.  Yes, recent posts.  Fixing the message will go a long way, I reckon.  You might also want to give a pass on downvoted posts.

Comment: @Hans - done, btw; only posts >= 0 are now counted

Comment: Great.  I'm guessing you'll hear more about this.  There are a fair number of contributors that delete ignored and forgotten un-upvoted posts.  They have a strong argument for > 0.

Comment: @Hans bring it on :) actually that isn't in jest; we can then figure out what their scenaio is and see how best to help